# What JDK do I need for Eclipse EE development

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I am running on MacOS Mojave 10.14.5 and I have the Java standard edition JDK installed (Java SE 13.0.1). Now I am downloading Eclipse for Java Enterprise Edition because I want to develop some EE apps. When I install Eclipse, it seems perfectly happy to use my Java SE JDK, even though I am downloading Eclipse for EE. Why is that? Can I actually develop an EE app with the SE JDK or do I need to download and install the Java EE JDK. I'm confused.

Comment: I would say, that's all right 99% of the times. You would pull the required dependencies on your project (e.g.: the Servlet API, annotations, etc.), so don't really need all of that installed on your Mac, it will be provided by the project, at a given stage.

Answer (score 0):

Java EE is several set of APIs which you write your program against.

An Compliant implementation requires Java SE and allows you to execute your program.

So Java EE is different than SE.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear: are you intent on using Java EE per se, i.e. making a web application using the APIs for Enterprise Java Beans (EJB), or do you just want a web app with a Java coded back end ?
I ask as Java EE is not the only back-end Java framework available and some of these allow Java SE - Spring being the most popular example of these.

Also, the version of Java EE or SE may be limited by what your IDE is configured for. So your IDE may not enable the most recent version of Java EE or SE.